# memory mapping to physical ram (hardware)

Tags: memory, memory-management

When the memory management unit translates a logical address to a physical address using the translation table, how does the physical address get mapped to that address in ram. What I mean to say, is that, how does it go to that address and not some other address? Does the particular memory address have some kind of uniqueness that seperates it from other addresses? Or does every 2 bytes In ram store one byte as the address and the other for data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every memory address (physical and virtual) is unique - a unique number. Four to eight bytes are usually used to identify a memory address, this creates a range of addresses called the address space. When the CPU architecture uses a 32-bit address space, the range of addresses is `0` to `4294967295`. When the CPU architecture uses a 64-bit address space, the range of addresses is `0` to `18446744073709551615`.

There's only two addresses stored in the translation table, a physical memory address and a virtual memory address. The address points to the first byte of large section in memory called a page. The size of this page is usually large, usually 4KB but is not standard. This way, the translation table does not have to store an address for every byte in memory (which is actually virtually impossible when the memory range is above 255 bytes).

Comment: hmmm. And I had one more doubt. Imagine that a process is in execution and the cpu generates an address which it stores in its program counter, which as we know is the address of the next instruction in the process. Now obviously all these instructions will be there in random addresses in the ram. So when the next instruction has to be fetched ,contents of the address register,i.e, the address bits, are sent to the ram through the address bus and enables that particular address in ram which it was pointing to. Now here's my doubt- How does it know which address to enable?

Comment: Does it have some sort of mechanism like every memory location has some extra bits allocated only as an identifier for other devices to know that this is the address which they want to access? (assuming DMA in the system)

Comment: The entries in the page tables do not actually store the virtual addresses. Only the physical page numbers. The tables are _indexed by_ the virtual addresses they describe.